# Is it possible to load sass variables from file into a map?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I want to have a map of all bootstrap vars i'm using in sass.

```
$FULL_MAP = ("bootstrap": @include(bootstrap/_variables.scss)
```

To achieve this, do I have to manually rewrite the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up manually putting required vars into a map and then using themify mixing in order to apply vars from the map. The code is on [github](https://github.com/batousik/angular-bootswatch-dynamic-seed) and this is the [file](https://github.com/batousik/angular-bootswatch-dynamic-seed/blob/master/src/style/themes/_themes.scss) that puts variables into the map

```
.custom-scope {
  @import "~bootswatch/dist/cerulean/variables";
  $cerulean: (
          "primary":$primary,
          "secondary":$secondary,
          "success":$success,
          "info":$info,
          "warning":$warning,
          "danger":$danger,
          "light":$light,
          "dark":$dark
  );
  $themes: map_merge($themes, ("cerulean": $cerulean)) !global;
}
```